# how to access form choose jQuery ? How to grab "%" from the amount that entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to built a fee calculator, and for that I need to access forms, I wondered if I can do it in jQuery.
So my code is that :

```
<form id="fee">
    <input type="text" title="fee" placeholder="Place the amount that you would like to send"/> $
    <input type="submit" onclick="getFee()"/>
</form>
<br/>
<p id="Here will be the fee"></p>
```

And the JS :

```
function getFee(){
    $("fee > input:fee").
}
```

Here is my problem. I want to know how to grab the amount that the user entered in the input and add to this amount of 10%, then print it in the paragraph below.

Comment: In the future, please try to be a little bit more coherent in your questions and provide a complete explanation of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all , add id to your input like this

```
<input type="text" id="amount"
```

Now get the value like this:

```
 var amount = $("#amount").val();
```

Don't use spaces in your ID

```
<p id="Here will be the fee"></p>
```

Use this instead

```
<p id="feeOnAmount"></p>
```

Now you can add `10%` to the amount like this

```
function getFee(){
    var amount = parseFloat($("#amount").val());
    if($.isNumeric(amount)){
        $("#feeOnAmount").html((amount * 1.1));    
    }
    else{
        $("#feeOnAmount").html("please enter a valid number");
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/E2rJQ/15/

Comment: You can simplify your arithmetic to `(amount * 1.1)`

Comment: Thank you very much ! Helped me alot ! 
And how I can clarify that the user enter only numbers?

Comment: You should use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`. try: `parseInt(010);`.

Comment: @ArthurChaykovski  . i have updated my answer with _number check_

Answer (score 0):

Use the # sign for id.  Also add an id to the input. `id="feeInput"`

Also title is not a valid input tag.

```
function getFee(){
        $("#fee > input#feeInput").
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getFee(){
    var inputVal = $("#fee > input[title='fee']").val();
    var inputFinal = parseInt(inputVal) + (parseInt(inputVal) * .10);

    //Change the ID of the p your appending to
    //ID is now = "calc"
    $("#calc").text(inputFinal);
}
```

Heres a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln3RN/

Answer (score 0):

I changed the output id and the selector.
[example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q77Yp/1/)

[attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fee")[0].onsubmit= getFee;

});
function getFee(){
        var feeInput = $('#fee > input[title="fee"]').val();
        feeInput = parseInt(feeInput);
        $('#Here_will_be_the_fee').text(feeInput*1.1);
        return false;
}
```

`getFee` returns false so that the form would not submit, only trigger onsubmit event.